# Impala rumbles upon cylinder deactivation

Tags: chevrolet, troubleshooting, vibration, impala

My 2008 Chevy Impala makes a rumble sound or vibration when going from 6-cylinder mode to 3-cylinder mode, with or without slight acceleration.

It sounds fine when it goes back into 6-cylinder mode. I am concerned. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I've made edits to the question to make the question more clear. Please feel free to make modifications if something has been lost in the editing.

Comment: Hows the oil level and when was the last time it was changed?

Comment: Oil Just done less than 1000 miles ago

Comment: And level is full

Comment: When was the last time it was fully serviced (tuned-up)? Is the Check Engine Light on? Any codes?

Comment: Never tuned up as far as I know, no engine light. And don’t know about codes .